# Is there any way to display a personal message when you hover mouse on any Java statement in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know it can be done using JavaDoc but what I want is a mouse listener that will display a message dialog. As soon as one hovers the mouse on String object, it should display some personal message like "This is a String object used to display a bunch of words together". The programmer shouldn't need to write comments like in JavaDoc.

Comment: The Java editor has lots of extension points for adding to its functionality see the JDT Plug-in Developer Guide in the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Java editor text hovers extension enables displaying messages on hovering the mouse.

https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaEditorTextHovers.html